Error: expected template.0.mappings to be a JSON object. Check the documentation for the expected format. unexpected end of JSON input
I'm facing a problem when running my module in tf cloud.
This is the current status:
I'm using terraform cloud version 1.4.5 with elastic stack module v0.11.0. This is for a dev env we usually deploy only for testing, so we need to destroy it every time we are not using it. The last working time was 2 months ago.
Today we tried to start the environment and found all our index templates are failing to create due to the following error:
Error: expected template.0.mappings to be a JSON object. Check the documentation for the expected format. unexpected end of JSON input
with module.index_template.elasticstack_elasticsearch_index_template.default["test-p1"]
on modules/index_template/main.tf line 30, in resource "elasticstack_elasticsearch_index_template" "default":
    mappings = each.value.mappings

We haven't done any changes to the file or it's variables since the last working session.
main.tf
1 # -----------------------------------> Providers Section <-----------------------------------
2 terraform {
3  required_version = ">= 1.4.5"
4 
5   required_providers {
6     elasticstack = {
7       source  = "elastic/elasticstack"
8       version = ">= 0.11.0"
9     }
10   }
11 }
12 resource "elasticstack_elasticsearch_index_template" "default" { # Creation of Index Templates
13   for_each = var.index_templates
14 
15   name           = each.key
16   priority       = each.value.priority
17   index_patterns = each.value.index_patterns
18
19   template {
20     settings = jsonencode({
21       number_of_shards             = each.value.number_of_shards,
22       number_of_replicas           = each.value.number_of_replicas,
23       "lifecycle.name"             = each.value.lifecycle_name,
24       refresh_interval             = each.value.refresh_interval,
25       max_docvalue_fields_search   = each.value.max_docvalue_fields_search,
26       "mapping.total_fields.limit" = each.value.total_fields_limit
27     })
28
29     mappings = each.value.mappings
30   }
31 }

variables.tf
 variable "index_templates" { # Creation of Index Templates (ixt)
  type = map(object({
    priority                   = number
    index_patterns             = list(string)
    number_of_shards           = number
    number_of_replicas         = number
    lifecycle_name             = string
    refresh_interval           = string
    max_docvalue_fields_search = number
    total_fields_limit         = number
    mappings                   = string
  }))

We tried upgrading to the module version 0.11.7 which is the current one but the behavior is persistent.

Seems the problem was the formating of the current variable, we were sending the following when no mappings were needed
mappings = ""
For some reason, terraform stopped liking this option and require to do it like this:
mappings = "{}"
Hope this helps somebody!!

FYI, I think this is the PR that changed the behaviour.  You said upgrading did not help – given this line version = ">= 0.11.0" I suspect you were already to the newest (incompatible) version, thus is downgrading (to a version not including that PR) that would have made the trick.
